# Is it legal to use Avast Free on a business PC?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, avast

We have a *really* small company ( 2 person ) and we just started it. There is a server with Windows XP (no need for Windows Server or anything else). Anyway, we need an anti-virus.

Is it legal to use Avast Free! on the machine? I couldn't find anyhting like an EULA or use rights. We really do NOT need any more protection. Its a single Firebird SQL server.

Comment: XP?!  You need to get off of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not, unfortunately. http://www.avast.com/free-antivirus-download says it's free only for "personal and non-commercial use"

Microsoft's Security Essentials seems good, and you can run it on 10 business machines.

Comment: Oh... damn Avast. :( I'm an Avast IS customer too (3 PCs license, still legit for 2 years). Would that work?

Comment: @Shiki  It would be best to sent the an e-mail and ask about it. I think that IS should work on commercial computers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use [ClamAV for Windows](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/about/win32/), the only feature not supported yet I suppose is real time scanning. It's open source so I don't think you should face any legal hassles if you use it for business.

Comment: ClamAV deleted some really important system files just a while back. I guess everyone removed their ClamAV for win copies. (It's just not for Windows / desktop, that's all.) Thanks for the suggesion though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with Rob.

The Avast site has separate pages for [home and home office](http://www.avast.com/en-gb/security-software-home-office) and [business](http://www.avast.com/en-gb/security-software-business) usage and only the home/home office page mentions the free version.

I think you could only use the free version if you were working *by yourself* from home.

Comment: I can't find it now, but for quite some time it was explicitly written on Avast's website that free version is only for non-commercial use and should not be used on any computer used for work. Maybe they changed that in the meantime, but I can't find the EULA right now anywhere (and I have Avast installed).

Comment: @AndrejaKo - I thought so too, but this is all I could find now.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Security Essentials is available for small businesses with up to 10 PCs. If your business has more than 10 PCs.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials

Comment: *> If your business has more than 10 PCs* … then what?

Answer (score 0):

[Avast for Business](http://www.avast.com/lp-business-security) (the new cloud product that is beta testing now in December 2014) has a free for business version that includes Mac, PC now and android later in 2015.  Free centralized management is included.

Comment: If you have some affliation with avast, you may want to disclose your affliation clearly and [have a look at the relevant help center topic](http://superuser.com/help/promotion). I'd add tho, generally licencing questions are out of our scope, and I'm surprised no one noticed this long.